# How do I write these using pipes in R?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse, aggregates

How do I get subgroups by using pipes? I don't understand why what I wrote doesn't work.  Can someone explain how these work, reading online and seeing examples online hasn't help me because I am not sure what I am not understanding?

```
mean(mtcars$qsec)



mtcars %>%
    select(qsec) %>%
    mean()
```

Warning message:
In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

```
mean(mtcars$qsec[mtcars$cyl==8])

mtcars %>%
     group-by(qsec) %>%
     filter(cyl==8)
     mean()
```

Error in mean.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

```
mean(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$hp > median(mtcars$hp)])

mtcars %>%
    group_by(mpg)  %>%
    filter(hp>median(hp))
    mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `select` still returns a data.frame with one column and `mean` expects a `vector` based on the `?mean`

> x - An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

We can use `pull` to extract the column as a `vector` and apply the `mean` on it

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   pull(qsec) %>%
   mean
#[1] 17.84875
```

---

In the second case, we are getting the `mean` of 'qsec' where 'cyl' is 8

```
mtcars %>%
   select(qsec, cyl) %>%
   filter(cyl == 8) %>% 
   pull(qsec) %>%
   mean
#[1] 16.77214
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up.  This is what I have for the last one.                             mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,hp) %>%
  filter(hp>median(hp)) %>%
  pull(mpg) %>%
  mean